# Polygons directive not respecting the visible property

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I'm attempting to use the [Angular Google Maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) module to display polygons on a google map but the uiGmapPolygons directive is not hiding/showing when the visible property of the model is modified.

Here's a plunker to illustrate the issue:
http://plnkr.co/edit/EhFihJRBK9Lb0s3mwMSl

Markup:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options" bounds="map.bounds">
    <ui-gmap-polygons models="polygons" path="'path'" stroke="'stroke'" visible="'visible'" fill="{ color: '#2c8aa7', opacity: '0.3' }">
    </ui-gmap-polygons>
     <ui-gmap-markers models="markers" idKey="'id'" options="'options'" coords="'coords'"></ui-gmap-markers>        
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Angular Code:

```
$scope.polygons = [{
  id: 1,
  path: [{
    latitude: 50,
    longitude: -80
  }, {
    latitude: 30,
    longitude: -120
  }, {
    latitude: 20,
    longitude: -95
  }],
  stroke: {
    color: '#6060FB',
    weight: 3
  },
  editable: true,
  draggable: true,
  geodesic: false,
  visible: true,
  fill: {
    color: '#ff0000',
    opacity: 0.8
  }
}];

$scope.toggle = function() {
  $scope.polygons[0].visible = !$scope.polygons[0].visible;
  $scope.markers[0].options.visible = !$scope.markers[0].options.visible;
};
```

I expect that when i change the visible property that the polygon would show/hide.

I'm not sure if I've found a bug or if I am attempting to adjust the visibility of the polygon incorrectly.

**EDIT:**

I submitted an issue on the module's github repo a few days ago and last night got a response that resolves the issue in version 2.0.11. Unfortuantely, I am using version 2.0.12.

Link to the github discussion around the issue:

```
https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1059
```

Comment: Having the same issue. You find anything out?

Comment: I submitted an issue on github a few days ago and just got a response yesterday. The commenter found a possible solution but it doesn't appear to resolve the issue in version 2.0.12.

[Issue 1059](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1059)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contributor nmccready fixed this issue back in January but at that point I'd already abandoned angular-google-maps.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

```
$scope.showPolygon = false;
$scope.toggelPolygon = function(){$scope.showPolygon=!$scope.showPolygon};
```

In your ui-gmap-polygon .....

```
visible='showPolygon'
```